# How to create new UserManager object inside controller after DBContext changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, usermanager

I want to have a refreshed UserManager object after my `DbContext` changed with new connectionString inside the Controller, I have injected the `UserManager` in the Controller but it's obvious that it will always have the last `DbContext` reference from DI, not to the newly created `dbcontext`.

I have tried like below.

```
this.DbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration, optionsBuilder.Options);
this._userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(DbContext), null, new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>(), null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

It works fine but it lacking most of the `UserManager` functionality like
`_userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password)` as I'm passing most of the parameter as null.
What should I do to get a fully working `UserManger` with new `DbContext` in simplest way?

Comment: Just curious why you’d want to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a service and use the UserManger in the service, then, configure the service using the Transient operations in the Startup.ConfigureServices method. The Transient operations are always different, a new instance is created with every retrieval of the service. Then, you could use this service in the controller. Please check the following steps:

create a UserManagerRepository service (in this service you can create methods and use the UserManager methods):

```
public interface IUserManagerRepository
{
    void Write(string message);
}
public class UserManagerRepository : IUserManagerRepository, IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UserManagerRepository(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public void Write(string message)
    {
        // _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync()
        Console.WriteLine($"UserManagerRepository: {message}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("UserManagerRepository.Dispose");
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Confiture the service using the following code in the Startup.ConfigureServices method:

```
 services.AddTransient<IUserManagerRepository, UserManagerRepository>();
```

After that, call the services manually in the controller action method.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var services = this.HttpContext.RequestServices;
        var log = (IUserManagerRepository)services.GetService(typeof(IUserManagerRepository));

        log.Write("Index method executing");
         
        var log2 = (IUserManagerRepository)services.GetService(typeof(IUserManagerRepository));

        log2.Write("Index method executing");
        var log3 = (IUserManagerRepository)services.GetService(typeof(IUserManagerRepository));

        log3.Write("Index method executing"); 
        return View();
    }
```

screenshot as below:

[image]

Reference:

[Tutorial: Use dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage)

[Dependency injection guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#idisposable-guidance-for-transient-and-shared-instances)

[Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#request-services)

Comment: so after calling the service again the userManager will be initialized with the newly created AppDbContext?

Comment: the _userManager still holds reference to the old dbContext, the new dbContext has a different connectionString

Comment: @SabirHossain of course, because the code injects `UserManager<IdentityUser>` which is provided by the identity model, that still depends on the configured `DbContext` (in your app startup). This answer is definitely not what you want.

Comment: I knew that, @Hopeless what can I do to refresh the UserManger with the newly created DbContext, you can see how I'm doing that but I need a fully functional UserManager

Answer (score -1):

Use Dependency Injection, that's how all of the mentioned tools are meant to be consumed.

```
private DbContext DbContext { get;}

private UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager { get; } 

public MyController(DbContext dbContext, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    DbContext = dbContext;
    UserManager = userManager;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

And here's a page on how to setup Dependency Injection for EF Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core

Assuming you already have `services.AddDefaultIdentity(...)` and `services.AddDbContext(...)`, injecting of `UserManager` and `YourProjectDbContext` should inherently just work in your Controllers.